# Messages not rendered when a pst is created from email messages located in another machine on a same network

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am creating a pst from message files which are located in another machine on a same network. But when I loaded the pst, messages are not rendered. I have added a screenshot. And code is below:

Issue do not occur when message files are imported from my local machine.

```
     private static void GeneratePST(string [] messageFiles, string outputPstPath)
    {
        RDOSession pstSession = null;
        RDOPstStore store = null;
        RDOFolder folder = null;
        RDOMail rdo_Mail = null;
        RDOItems items = null;
        try
        {
            pstSession = new RDOSession();
            store = pstSession.LogonPstStore(outputPstPath, 1, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputPstPath));
            folder = store.IPMRootFolder;
            folder = folder.Folders.Add("Loose Messages");
            foreach (string messages in messageFiles)
            {
                items = folder.Items;
                rdo_Mail = items.Add("IPM.NOTE");
                rdo_Mail.Import(messages, rdoSaveAsType.olMSG);
                rdo_Mail.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo_Mail);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
            pstSession.Logoff();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pstSession);
            GC.Collect();
        }      
    }
```

[image: email messages not rendered]

I have also impersonated the network machine before importing message file. But still the issue persist.

The problem only exists for files in another machine. Messages are rendered for msg file located in my machine. Also, I noticed issue is only with message files. Eml file are rendered. So, it might not be the issue of impersonation.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not support accessing PST files on network drives. They must be on a local machine.

Also, there is no reason to continuously retrieve the RDOItems object - you never release on the old value, so those objects stay alive until your app exits. Ditto for the rdo_Mail object:

```
        folder = folder.Folders.Add("Loose Messages");
        items = folder.Items;
        foreach (string messages in messageFiles)
        {
            if (rdo_Mail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdo_Mail);
            rdo_Mail = items.Add("IPM.NOTE");
            rdo_Mail.Import(messages, rdoSaveAsType.olMSG);
            rdo_Mail.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Actually, I am just importing loose msg files. Those msg files are on the network drive. Do you mean to say that those msg files cannot be imported even after impersonating? However, eml files were imported successfully which are on that same network drive.

Comment: MSG file should be Ok. Does it make any difference if you load them from a local folder?